# archlinux upgrade package-query fails to init alpm lib

Tags: linux, arch-linux

I recently upgraded archlinux with pacman -Syu, i read on the website that i had to do a couple more manual steps to keep yaourt.
I uninstalled yaourt and package-query, did the upgrade, downloaded package-query from the website, compiled it and installed it.
But pacman still cannot find the package yaourt, i tried to launch package-query alone, but it told me pacman.conf was not found in /usr/local/etc. I created a symbolic link to /etc/pacman.conf.

Now when i start package-query i have this error :

```
failed to initialize alpm library
```

I have found some libalpm.so in /usr/lib but i still don't get the error.
I tried to search for the error on the forum but none of the solution worked for me.
Is there anyone who knows why i have this error and how i can solve it ?

EDIT : i didn't build the right package-queryn i downloaded the proper tar file and used makepkg -si and package-query works, but pacman doesn't find yaourt.

EDIT2 : I readded the repository of yaourt to pacman.conf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have compiled package-query (or perhaps pacman itself) incorrectly – without specifying the main prefix and some other paths, an autotools-based program will use default paths that completely do not match the FHS ones.

I'm guessing you visited the [package-query](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/package-query) page on AUR, completely ignored the "Package Actions" box, and just downloaded & compiled the tarball under "Sources". Those do not contain a pacman package, just the upstream source code.

Empty your `/usr/local`, then build the *real* "package-query" package from AUR, using the "[Download tarball](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/pa/package-query/package-query.tar.gz)" link and running `makepkg` on the extracted results.

Comment: i also tried running makepkg but it just told me there was no PKGBUILD, i guess i missed something there.

Comment: ok but in my defense, the action box is not attractive enough. i got package-query to work. But pacman -S yaourt still doesn't work, it doesn't find the package

Comment: Nevermind i readded the repository to pacman.conf and it is working. Thanks for your help